# R highcharts multiple stacked bar chart

Tags: r, highcharts, bar-chart

I want to plot a multiple stacked bar chart, but I don't know how to combine the r code.

```
  Closing Date Non Current Assets Current Assets Non Current Liabilities
2      2013/12           13637344       13078654                 9376243
3      2014/12           14075507       12772388                 8895126
4      2015/12           14578093       14226181                 9715914
5      2016/12           10911628       10205708                 9810157
6      2017/12           10680998       10950779                13493110
   Current Liabilities
2             5075985
3             4963856
4             5992229
5             8859263
6             4094183
```

I can plot multiple bar chart by:

```
    highchart() %>% 
    hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
    hc_xAxis(categories = bs.table$`Closing Date`) %>%
    hc_add_series(name="Non Current Assets",data = bs.table$`Non Current 
    Assets`) %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Current Assets",data = bs.table$`Current Assets`) %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Non Current Liabilities",data = bs.table$`Non Current Liabilities`) %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Current Liabilities",data = bs.table$`Current Liabilities`) %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_ft())
```

[image]

and only one stacked bar like this:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "MyGraph") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(
    dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
    stacking = "normal",
    enableMouseTracking = FALSE)
  ) %>% 
  hc_series(list(name="Current Assets",data=bs.table$`Current Assets`),
            list(name="Non Current Assets",data=bs.table$`Non Current Assets`))
```

[image]

my desired output is like this:
[image]

I try to combine the code by adding:

```
%>% hc_series(list(name="Current Liabilities",data=bs.table$`Current Liabilities`),
            list(name="Non Current Liabilities",data=bs.table$`Non Current Liabilities`))
```

on the second code but it doesn't work, it added up the same bar. Please advice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify which bars belong in which groups by adding `stack` to each series, like this:

```
library(highcharter)

bs.table = data.frame(
  Closing.Date = paste(2013:2017, 12, sep = "/"),
  Non.Current.Assets = c(13637344, 14075507, 14578093, 10911628, 10680998),
  Current.Assets = c(13078654, 12772388, 14226181, 10205708, 10950779),
  Non.Current.Liabilities = c(9376243, 8895126, 9715914, 9810157, 13493110),
  Current.Liabilities = c(5075985, 4963856, 5992229, 8859263, 4094183)
)

highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = bs.table$Closing.Date) %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Non Current Assets",
                data = bs.table$Non.Current.Assets,
                stack = "Assets") %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Current Assets",
                data = bs.table$Current.Assets,
                stack = "Assets") %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Non Current Liabilities",
                data = bs.table$Non.Current.Liabilities,
                stack = "Liabilities") %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Current Liabilities",
                data = bs.table$Current.Liabilities,
                stack = "Liabilities") %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_ft())
```

(To group by current vs. non-current instead of assets vs. liabilities, just rename `stack` in each series appropriately.)