# How to Correct Empty Plot area using highchart() and Lists

Tags: r, r-highcharter

Using the Stack Overflow: [R highcharts multiple stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54651243/r-highcharts-multiple-stacked-bar-chart)

I am able to create a stacked column chart using the dataset I have.  However, the data "types" in this set are dynamic so I am attempting to implement :
[Highcharter stacked column groupings not using hchart()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671973/highcharter-stacked-column-groupings-not-using-hchart?rq=1)

However, while the list I am generating appears identical to the example if I download and run that code, the plot shows up empty.  The lenged correctly identifies the types, but the chart does not populate.  I have tried running this in a browser in case R studio was not handling it correctly but to no avail.

I have attempted and have working a partial solution using:
[R highcharts multiple stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54651243/r-highcharts-multiple-stacked-bar-chart)

However, because of the dynamic type of data, I need more of a solution similar to:
[Highcharter stacked column groupings not using hchart()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671973/highcharter-stacked-column-groupings-not-using-hchart?rq=1)

I have compared the lists and they appear identical (different data but the structure is correct)

```
data <- data[!duplicated(data$AcctID), ]

data$ExpireDate <- mdy_hm(data$ExpireDate)
data$ExpireDateGroup <- floor_date(data$ExpireDate, "day")

cheeseData <- data %>%
  mutate(Day = as.character(ExpireDateGroup)) %>%
  group_by(Day, Cheese) %>%
  summarise(CheeseWheels = n())

byCheese.list <- cheeseData %>%
  group_by(Cheese) %>%
  do(cheeseData = list_parse2(.[, c('Day', 'CheeseWheels')])) %>%
  rename(name = Cheese) %>%
  mutate(Cheese = 'column') %>%
  list_parse()

highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = cheeseData$Day) %>%
  hc_add_series_list(byCheese.list) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = 'normal'))
```

Expected Results: There should be a stacked column chart
[image: Empty Column Chart]

Sample Data

```
    data <- structure(list(AcctID = c(251981L, 261775L, 275048L, 282754L, 
                          286490L, 279683L, 277289L, 282031L, 287776L, 284062L), CreatedDate = c("4/2/2019 18:48", 
                                                                                                 "4/18/2019 16:14", "5/10/2019 7:49", "5/22/2019 15:13", "5/29/2019 11:29", 
                                                                                                 "5/17/2019 14:05", "5/14/2019 10:32", "5/21/2019 16:59", "5/31/2019 7:56", 
                                                                                                 "5/24/2019 14:09"), ExpireDate = structure(c(1559642040, 1559642100, 
                                                                                                                                              1559642160, 1559642220, 1559642220, 1559642280, 1559642340, 1559642340, 
                                                                                                                                              1559642400, 1559642460), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
               Cheese = c("Gouda", "Gouda", "Gouda", "Gouda", "Gouda", "Gouda", 
                          "Gouda", "Gouda", "Gouda", "Gouda"), ExpireDateGroup = structure(c(1559606400, 
                                                                                             1559606400, 1559606400, 1559606400, 1559606400, 1559606400, 
                                                                                             1559606400, 1559606400, 1559606400, 1559606400), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                        "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L), class = "data.frame")
```